# Issue on reading parquet file when running Spark (Scala) on a cluster

Tags: apache-spark

Hope someone can help on the error we encountered.

Overview: Our cluster is Datalab cluster and users will need to access the Juggernaut cluster (data source).

we tried the reading using the following codes:              sql.Context.parquetFile("hdfs://juggernaut/data/dw/usa/cem_mbb/flowCell/date=20181009")     sqlContext.reload.load("hdfs://juggernaut/data/dw/usa/cem_mbb/flowCell/date=20181009")
sqlContext.read.parquet("hdfs://juggernaut/data/dw/usa/cem_mbb/flowCell/date=20181009")

1. Running on local Spark - Output: **OK**
2. Running Spark on Scala - **encountered the error log below**.

We keep on having the error below on Spark.

> 18/10/17 17:59:05 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID
>   1, hdp007-r1.datalab.smart.local.ph): java.io.IOException: Could not
>   read footer: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file
>   FileStatus{path=hdfs://juggernaut/data/dw/usa/cem_mbb/flowCell/date=20181009/09-part-01-usa_cem_mbb_sdr_flowCell-20181009154019-r-00000.parquet;
>   isDirectory=false; length=1070652650; replication=0; blocksize=0;
>   modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=;
>   permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false}
>                 at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readAllFootersInParallel(ParquetFileReader.java:247)
>                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anonfun$27.apply(ParquetRelation.scala:786)
>                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anonfun$27.apply(ParquetRelation.scala:775)
>                 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$22.apply(RDD.scala:717)
>                 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$22.apply(RDD.scala:717)
>                 at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>                 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
>                 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
>                 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>                 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
>                 at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
>                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file
>   FileStatus{path=hdfs://juggernaut/data/dw/usa/cem_mbb/flowCell/date=20181009/09-part-01-usa_cem_mbb_sdr_flowCell-20181009154019-r-00000.parquet;
>   isDirectory=false; length=1070652650; replication=0; blocksize=0;
>   modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=;
>   permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false}
>                 at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:239)
>                 at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:233)
>                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>                 ... 3 more

Comment: Could please check how to provide a [mcve] and [edit] your question accordingly?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @jpdeleon :) In order to get better answers and to avoid downvotes, please share your code and what you have tried so far. Thanks.